# Delete Site Features

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

I deleted all my Site Features with an c# program.

```
SPFarm.Local.Solution.Remove(Solution name);
```

Unfortunately the features still appear in my Web Site > Site Settings > Site Features

Have anybody a approach to delete the Features in my Web Site?

If I look at \Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\Template\Features all my Features appear,
but they do not appear in the Central Administration > Operations > Solution Management.

I am using WSS 3.0

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Delete farm features: SPFarm.Local.FeatureDefinitions.Remove(Guid);

Delete site features: SPContext.Current.Site.FeatureDefinitions.Remove(Guid);

Comment: SPContext.Current.Site.FeatureDefinitions.Remove(Guid);
with this code i get the error that the feature isn't activated. If i activate the feature in the site, i get the same error. You know any other possibilty?

Comment: @Fabian You could use the `stsadm -o uninstallfeature` command in the cmd.exe. That way it will 100% be removed from your sharepoint site.